# Ability to install Ubuntu on Asus PU500CA

Tags: laptop, asus, compatibility

I'm going to buy and start using Ubuntu on Asus PU500CA  with i5 processor (http://www.asus.com/Commercial_Notebook/ASUSPRO_ESSENTIAL_PU500CA/#specifications) and wanted to ask you for advice - doesn't it seems that it'll work OK on this laptop, or some of its hardware seems to work not quite OK?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks very nice. I am not quite sure about the cardreader and the fingerprint scanner but it seems to me that installing ubuntu on this piece of hardware would be no problem. You can't get much closer that that (or you should buy from a linux shop or Dell's ubuntu developer notebook)

I can't say more than that because to be sure I would need to know the brand and type of every piece of hardware they listed in the specifications. Until then it still is an educated guess.

(although my experience says that you practically can't go wrong with that laptop...Asus notebooks have in my experience always a high linux compatibility factor and the intel videodriver is 100% supported by open source drivers)